What is this kind of relationship among a set of given functions called?
I was learning about inverse functions, the book mentioned if
$$y=f(x)$$
$$x=g(y)$$
then the functions $f$ and $g$ are said to be inverse of each other. My question is what is the following kind of relationship among the functions $f,g,h$ called?
$$y=f(x)$$
$$z=g(y)$$
$$x=h(z)$$
I tried looking up the internet but couldn't find the specific results.

This is incorrect. $f : A \to B$ and $g : B \to A$ are inverses iff, for all $x : A, y : B$, $(y = f(x)) \Leftrightarrow (x = g(y))$. Do you mean a similar statement, universally quantifying over $x$, $y$ and $z$?

If so, then it's not hard to see that $f$ is an inverse to $h \circ g$, $g$ is an inverse to $f \circ h$ and $h$ is an inverse to $g \circ f$, so you have a commuting triangle of isomorphisms. It's not called anything specific.

@NaïmFavier I was looking for a general term for such relationship among three or more functions, but turns out there isn't one, thanks.
